# How do I travel through TagGroups in python dm-script

Tags: python, tags, traversal, dm-script

How do I use unknown structures of `TagGroup`s in [dm-script](/questions/tagged/dm-script) in python?

---

`TagGroup`s are widely used in *DigitalMicrograph*. But how do I travel through them in python? How do I get all available tag names?

In normal `dm-script` there are functions like `TagGroupGetTagLabel()` and `TagGroupGetTagType()`. One can use a `for`-loop to check the structure. But there is not a single function in the python wrapper class `Py_TagGroup` to get information about the labels. Also the examples never deal with unknown `TagGroup`s.

---

I have a very simple problem: I want to use (show, modify, check, save, ...) the tags from an image. But I don't know the tag names.

```py
img = camera.AcquireImage()
tg = img.GetTagGroup()
```

But now what? I don't know anything about this `TagGroup`. `TagGroup`s are not iterable so I cannot use them in `for`-loops. I can get their length but I can only access data at indices. And that only if I know the datatype. Neither can I get the type nor the label.

---

So again: How can I travel through `TagGroup`s in python in [dm-script](/questions/tagged/dm-script)? How can I get the structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Python module `execdmscript` on [GitHUB](https://github.com/miile7/execdmscript) with (version ≥ 1.1.4) supports converting `Py_TagGroup`s to python `dict`s or `list`s. So the following code works for me:

```py
import execdmscript

img = camera.AcquireImage()
tg = img.GetTagGroup()

# convert the Py_TagGroup object to a python dict
tg = execdmscript.convert_from_taggroup(tg)

for key in tg:
    print(key, tg[key])
```

> **Disclaimer**: I am the author of the [`execdmscript`](https://github.com/miile7/execdmscript) module. Still there is no easy solution<sup>1</sup> for this problem at the moment so I am sure this is the best solution.

---

<sup>1</sup>`execdmscript.convert_from_taggroup()` uses the persistent tags and `dm-script` code for this. It involves saving the `Py_TagGroup` to the global tags. Since `dm-script` code can travel through `TagGroup`s, the strucutre of the `TagGroup` is analyzed by executing `dm-script` code from the python interpreter. The results are saved to the persistent tags again. Then the structure is read from the global tags with python and a `dict` or `list` can be created from it.

Answer (score 1):

The Python API is only a subset of the DM-script API and initial releases unfortunately lacked some important commands. If you feel a particular command missing, please report it as feature request at Gatan's "issue reporting" form.

GMS 3.4.2 does not seem to contain the necessary commands to do what you want (in Python)

BTW, tagGroups *are* iterable.

```
taggroup tg = NewTagGroup()
tg.TagGroupSetTagAsString("a","A")
tg.TagGroupSetTagAsString("b","B")
tg.TagGroupSetTagAsString("d","d")
tg.TagGroupSetTagAsString("c","C")

string str
tg.tagGroupGetIndexedTagAsString(2,str)
Result("\n str:" + str)

tg.TagGroupOpenBrowserWindow("",0)
```

Comment: With *iterable* I mean [python iterable](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-iterable) (or even better [python mappings](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#collections.abc.Mapping)) so objects can be used in `for` loops directly. `Py_TagGroup` neither has an `__iter__` nor an `__getitem__` function so in python terms it is not iterable. I should have stated more explicitly that I was talking about python terms, sorry for that :)